# How to send logs from rsyslog to kafka?

Tags: bash, apache-kafka, ansible, udp, rsyslog

I wrote an ansible that disables Selenix and ufw for the host and runs a bash script. The bash script takes an integer input and prints that number of lines, which includes the timestamp and 32 random characters. Now I want this output to go to the udp port and rsyslog send the logs to Kafka. So I don't know how to do the last task. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Thanks

### Ansible playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: My playbook
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Disabling SELinux state
      selinux:
        state: disabled

    - name: Stop and disable firewalld.
      service:
         name: ufw
         state: stopped
         enabled: False

    - name: Copy unit file
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /home/AnsiblePlaybooks/files/mytest.service
        dest: /etc/systemd/system/mytest.service
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0644'

    - name: Copy app file    
      template:
        src: /home/ansible-test/AnsiblePlaybooks/app.sh
        dest: /home/app.sh
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0644'

    - name: reload daemons
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        daemon_reload: yes

    - name: Enable mytest.service
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        name: mytest.service
        state: started
        enabled: yes
```

### bash script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

num = {{ input_var }} 
for i in $(seq 1 $num) ; do
    echo =============================
    echo "$i: $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S) $(openssl rand -hex 16)"
    sleep 0.5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.3.0/connect/quickstart.html#start-the-services) (or create your own producer) to send the data to Kafka; You'll use Ansible to setup the host and deploy the configuration files for the connector.